# Android Studio "Variable is never used", but actually is used (BigInteger Problem, unsolved reference)

Tags: java, android, kotlin

So, good day eveyone.

I'm starting to write my very first own app with kotlin via Android Studio, and I have one problem that I cannot solve. When writing down this code: *(bi is used infront of every variable that is a BigInteger btw.)*

```
if (length == 2) {
     val bicombinations: BigInteger = valueOf(bivariations.toLong())
           .multiply(bivariations)
    }
```

it tells me, that "bicombinations" is never used. However, I actually use it in this line here:

```
val biresult: BigInteger = bicombinations.divide(bipcpower)
```

At this line, I get another error/warning for bicombinations, "unsolved reference: bicombinations"

**EDIT: The second warning now went to: "Variable 'bicombinations' must be initialized."** I know how to fix this when using an Int or Double or whatever, but since BigIntegers are vals, I just cannot set a value on bicombinations outside the if statement

**EDIT 2: That's how the initialization problem is solved:** First, declare bicombinations outside the if branch like so:

```
var bicombinations: BigInteger = ONE
```

and inside the if branch, just use bicombinations without the "val" before it, and don't declare it as a BigInteger again. Thanks @Elliot-frisch

Can anyone tell me what to do? This would really help me finishing my app!

Comment: variable is only created when if condition is true so there maybe an option where the variable isn't set so error of unresolved reference is thrown.

Comment: You are limiting the ***scope*** to the ***block***.

Comment: @Animesh look at my reply to the other comment. Halfway of the problem is solved

Comment: And @elliot what do you mean with that?

Comment: `if (x) { val z = "foo"; }` - where does `z` exist? In the scope of the block `{}`. Outside `{}` there is no `z`. Inside `{}` there is a `z`. That is called **scope**.

Comment: Compare with `var z = null; if (x) { z = "foo"; }` now `z` is declared and initialized before the block, so it is not limited to visibility in the block. Notice the assignment in the block does not include `val` (or `var`). That's because this example does **not** limit the visibility to the block.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch So do you mean I should set bicombination to null before the if branch/block? That wouldn't work I guess, since BigInteger is a val and I can not set a value to it’s twice.. But maybe you mean something different, if so, please tell me!

Comment: `var bicombination: BigInteger = BigInteger.ONE;` - look now it's a **`var`** (not a `val`). Or you can just keep complaining that the way you want to do it doesn't work.

Comment: See my answer for initializing issue

Comment: Thanks both Elliott & Mohammad! Elliots solution worked, that's why I dint't try out yours, but thank you nonetheless!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Until there is a guarantee of a variable is set, the variable is not in scope (aka in reference), so you may need to set the variable in all the condition before using it outside the if condition.

Either move the result code inside the if branch

```kotlin
if (length == 2) {
    val bicombinations: BigInteger = valueOf(bivariations.toLong())
        .multiply(bivariations)
    val biresult: BigInteger = bicombinations.divide(bipcpower)
}
```

or add an else branch to if that ensures the variable `bicombination` is set

```kotlin
val bicombinations: BigInteger
if (length == 2) {
    bicombinations = valueOf(bivariations.toLong())
        .multiply(bivariations)
} else {
    bicombination = BigInteger(0)
}
val biresult: BigInteger = bicombinations.divide(bipcpower)
```

Comment: As stated in the other comment: The value is never used is now gone thanks to your idea, the must be initialized is still there tho..

Comment: If you add a proper else branch as mentioned in my answer must initialized should have been gone, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, it did, the second warning got changed though, not went away entirely. I edited in my original post.

Comment: @KenzoVolgmann What do you want to do? specifically what is your implementation of else branch

Comment: I need the else branch because I have different outputs depending on the length of the input, so for every length of the input I need different-working if branches

Answer (score 1):

Change your code like below (Need to define your variable outside if block)

```
val bicombinations: BigInteger

if (length == 2) {
 bicombinations = valueOf(bivariations.toLong())
       .multiply(bivariations)
}
```

Comment: As stated in the other comment: The value is never used is now gone thanks to your idea, the must be initialized is still there tho..

Comment: Then initialize it to a value like zero

Comment: This would not work, since BigIntegers are always vals and so cant be reassigned

Answer (score 1):

```
val biresult=0.toBigInteger()
```

This way you can initialize biresult.
When you define a variable in if statement, you can't use it out of that and you get unresolved reference error. You should define it in your function not to get this error.